# Insert element into list of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Have a following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"booking": ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   "route": [['1','2','3'],['5','4','1'],['3','6','8']]})
```

1. need to insert into each "route" cell the '0' at the beginning of `list` to get this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"booking": ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                    "route": [['0','1','2','3'],['0','5','4','1'],['0','3','6','8']]})
```

2. and next step is to `split` route by legs, to get this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"booking": ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                    "legs": [['0>1','1>2','2>3'],['0>5', '5>4','4>1'],['0>3','3>6','6>8']]})
```

Comment: do you want a copy or to modify the DataFrame in place? The logic would be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
df1 = df.assign(route=[[0]+l for l in df['route']])
```

Output:

```
  booking         route
0       A  [0, 1, 2, 3]
1       B  [0, 5, 4, 1]
2       C  [0, 3, 6, 8]
```

Then:

```
df1 = df.assign(route=[[f'{a}>{b}' for a,b in zip(l, l[1:])]
                       for l in df1['route']])
```

Output:

```
  booking            route
0       A  [0>1, 1>2, 2>3]
1       B  [0>5, 5>4, 4>1]
2       C  [0>3, 3>6, 6>8]
```

Of course, as commented by @Nick, you can use a single step if the intermediate is not needed:

```
df1 = df.assign(route=[[f'{a}>{b}' for a,b in zip([0] + l, l)]
                       for l in df['route']])
```

Output:

```
  booking            route
0       A  [0>1, 1>2, 2>3]
1       B  [0>5, 5>4, 4>1]
2       C  [0>3, 3>6, 6>8]
```

Comment: df1 = df.assign(route=[[0]+l for l in df['route']]) --- for this, if need to insert into somewhere else new cell, then how better to do it?

Comment: Why not just `df1 = df.assign(route=[[f'{a}>{b}' for a,b in zip([0] + l, l)] for l in df['route']])`?

Comment: @Nick sure you can use a single step, OP seemed to want to have two

Comment: @bluekit46 can you clarify?

Comment: @mozway yeah, need to have two

Comment: @mozway oh well, fair enough, seems odd given step 2 overwrites step 1, but mine is not to reason why...